# How to properly record electric guitar?

Tags: guitar, recording, homerecording, production

I want to record my electric guitar for the sake of making covers as well as my own music, however I'm having trouble getting a good tone. I have 3 possible approaches (one of which has worked fairly well)

1. Plug my guitar into my Scarlett 2i2 and use the amps in Garageband. [This has worked decently well for me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oaqQ3p2U6y9MOCXkEpxWnHAt2vU8P1Y7/view?usp=sharing).
2. Try to record my amps directly with [my microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XOXRTX6). [This is what it sounds like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hRrK0P3sNBsotj4ry2geYONsL_SudoQ-/view?usp=sharing). It sounds very... lackluster. I can hear the pick hitting the strings, everything sounds muddy and cheap. For reference, I'm using a Boss GT-6 for effects and a Fender Frontman 25R for the amp.
3. Plug my Boss GT-6 directly into the interface and record its output directly since it has preamp and speaker simulation built in. **Disclaimer:** I haven't tried this approach yet.

Option 1 is super easy to set up, I just need my guitar and a cable, and as a bonus I can tweak the sound as much as I want even after having recorded (which is pretty convenient). It's what I currently use and it's not broken by any means, so if that's standard practice then I can keep doing it.

However, I really wanted Option 2 to work though because when practicing you get everything to sound just right to your ears, and it'd be nice to be able to convert that directly to a recording. For instance, I sometimes practice on a [mini-amp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PDJXGIG) and I love the lo-fi/garage rock sound, especially when practicing Strokes songs. It sounds perfect to my ears, but I know that if I put the mic to it, it'll sound bad.

Is there a trick I'm missing to recording? Do I need a better quality microphone? How do I get rid of the picking sounds?

**Note:** I can't really turn the amp up any louder since I have roommates :( so if that's the only solution then I'll just have to stick with the digital methods

Comment: In your Option 2, it sounds like the mic is out in the room, not right on the speaker grille, where it should be.  Sounds really boomy and roomy, not tight and focused.  And I'm not hearing any picking sounds, but at 0:11 I do hear what sounds like someone stomping on the footswitch of a pedal.  That shouldn't be audible if your mic placement is right.

Comment: @DataProcessing I actually had the mic right up to the amp, and I put a small fleece blanket around the two (probably not the most insulating, but more than nothing I reckon). As for the sound at 0:11, that was actually me flipping the pickup switch on my guitar. You're right that it overall is boomy+roomy but I'm not sure how to stop that (short of hanging anechoic foam on my walls)

Comment: Are you certain you had the front of the mic capsule pointed toward the amp and not backwards?  If you had things set up correctly, there's no way it should sound like your sample.

Comment: @DataProcessing I looked up the response of the microphone and it's a cardioid, which means even though the microphone _looks_ symmetric, there is indeed a front and a back... oops. I didn't take that into account and just made sure one of the faces was up against the amp. It's entirely possible (and kinda likely) that the mic was facing the wrong way...

Comment: The trick to recording is that it’s a skill just as complicated as playing guitar and it takes just as many years of daily practice to learn to do it well. The other trick is that the cheapest gear usually sounds like it’s the cheapest.

Comment: You really do need someone in an isolate booth who can hear what's going on as you change mic positions and so on.  Or make notes of several scenarios, record on each, and carefully listen to them all.  There's no advice that will replace a great ear and a WHOLE LOT of experimentation.  Even experts take HOURS and HOURS setting up mics for a recording session.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you get a good tone with inside-the-box GarageBand amps? Or you'd like to record the same sound as you're hearing? Then why not start practicing with GarageBand too, so practicing sound is the same as recording sound? What's the thing with the GT-6, is the tone not good enough? Get a better external amp sim?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I can get good tones out of GarageBand, but it's easier to practice with my real effects board. Practicing with GarageBand seems a bit tedious since I have to create a project and track just to hear the guitar (though this is null if I'm recording a song since I have all this ready anyways). I haven't tried the GT-6 so I'm not sure how it would sound, but the main issue is I want to record what I hear, and switching the GT-6 output from my amp to my laptop seems like it would effect the sound.

Comment: @rcplusplus Did you do another test with the mic oriented the correct way?

Comment: @DataProcessing I found out where the front of the microphone is and then recorded my guitar, [here is the result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iwe_fmsSBzTjtOscTh-zUyjgQJwUCB_V/view?usp=sharing). It sounds a lot better I think! I did some EQ-ing in garageband to clean it up a bit, but I think to get it better than this it'll be as ToddWilcox and Bennyboy1973 said: I'm just gonna have to take time and fiddle with everything until the sound is just right!

Comment: Much better; that was definitely the problem in your first recording.  Just wear some decent headphones and gradually move the mic around the front of the speaker until you find where the sweet spots are.  Usually about 1" off the speaker grille and close to the center of the speaker cap is where you'll find some good tones.

Answer (score 4):

Option 2 is the traditional way and would still be considered the “proper” one by many engineers. Obviously though, the Frontman isn't exactly a boutique amp, so you shouldn't be surprised if this doesn't give results that are as good as what you hear on professional records. To go the amp route you should

- Have an amp whose sound you really like. Typically that would mean all-tube with a nice cabinet, what exactly depends of course on the genre.
- Run it *without* digital pre-simulation. If you use a digital multi-FX, make sure that it simulates only stuff that could also be done with analogue stompboxes, but in particular no cabinet emulation.
- Use a room with good acoustics. Actually this isn't so critical for guitar amp as it is for other situations, but it's important that the room doesn't have weird resonant reflections. What tends to work well is acoustically “dead” rooms, for example a crammed guest bedroom in the attic. Reverb can be added later on.
- Turn it up *loud*. Practice volume is no use here, you want a master volume near the amp's limit to both get the right sound and reduce parasitic noise.
  Note that it isn't so much the absolute volume that matters but the *local* volume at the mic'd speaker, and the fact that all parts of the amp are actually driven to near-saturation, to unfold its full sound complexity. That's why *very small all-tube amps* make a lot of sense for recording.
- Mic it well. There's no single right way to do this, but certainly pointing a cardoid mic in the wrong direction is rather questionable...

If you can't achieve all of this, then you're nowadays likely to get better results by digital emulation. That doesn't mean the amp is worthless, but it should be understood as just a monitor to get the playing right with no latency issues. But what you actually record should be the direct guitar signal before amp. You *could* record through the Boss with cabinet emulation, but I wouldn't recommend it – modern amp-sim DAW plugins are generally better and you have more flexibility tweaking the sound during mixing instead of tracking. So better just split off the signal before the amp with a DI box (make sure it's a high-impedance active one) and record that. Then use amp simulation in the computer to get the final sound.

Answer (score 3):

All 3 at once.

- Mic'd amp because you know how it sounds and what you record is what you get
- DI'd signal so you have something to re-amp if you don't like #1
- GT-6 because why not?

Then at mix time you can work with a blend of the 3 to achieve whatever you want.

Comment: out of curiosity, is this a common tactic with home recording and/or studio recording? Also, how do I get the signal to go across multiple routes like that? Do I just looks for a signal splitter device?

Comment: I have an interface (stealth pedal) that has two mono instrument inputs. The chain could be: guitar > Y-splitter > one branch off Y to one input on interface; 2nd Y branch to amp with mic > (preamp) > 2nd interface input. Two separate tracks: arm DI on one; arm mic on the other. Hit record.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the 'true' sound of an electric guitar.   You've described three valid methods of recording yours.

Direct connection plus Garageband effects gives a pleasing result?  Good.

A cheap microphone that looks designed to flatter close-miced vocals was less successful.  OK.  Maybe it overloaded.  Maybe you should point it at a different part of  of the speaker cone, from a different distance. Maybe you had it pointing the wrong way!   Maybe it's just the wrong mic.  A SM57 is traditional for this job.   Carry on experimenting.

There's a third option that you haven't tried yet.  Exciting!

Obviously if you CAN get a  useful result without deafening the neighbours, that's a plus!   I don't know if there's much point in miking a guitar amp unless it's working pretty hard.